# iOS - ViewController of type MyCustomViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have my ViewController, `MyWebViewController` where I use a `webView`, created in xib. `.h` file has

```
@interface MyWebViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
```

in `.m` file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

Here is my xib[image]

It works perfect for me.

Later I create another ViewController, `RootViewController` of type `MyWebViewController`.

```
#import "MyWebViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : MyWebViewController
```

The xib of `MyViewViewController` is loaded as expected, but the `webView` is not loaded to the xib. I spent more time in debugging.

Later, I removed the `webView` from xib and created it programmatically.

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 441)];
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Creating the webView programmatically gives the expected output.

I need a little clarification that, why was my `webView` not loaded, when it was created in xib, and, works fine when it was created programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to change in iOS9 view loading behavior. Developer is supposed to update the UI elements in `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `-viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

In your *RootViewController*, did you call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This way it will trigger the base class function and *webView* will load expectedly. You forget to put this in `MyWebViewController` as well.

**EDIT :**

The reason `self.webView` is not getting load in derived class is because it is marked `IBOutlet` so it needs a reference of pre-allocated element from `UIView` or `xib` and in the derived class we are *not* instatiating base view file e.g., `MyWebViewController.xib`. So `self.webView` appears nil and function call on nil getting ignored silently. So, once you do it by code it is independent of xib file and works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added in both viewControllers. But no change.